# Send Notification emails when owner of account changes

Tags: email, email-template

I have a batch process which reassigns owner of an account based on certain conditions. Now i need to also send emails to previous owners of the account that the account is been reassigned. What is the best way to do this?

Is there someway we can utilize which is email notification available on salesforce while transfer of ownership?

If writing a code to send email is the only way out, what should be the best practice while sending emails from a batch process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is only idea for such functionality:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BriZAAS

In my opinion sending emails from code (in finish method ) is best way.
It also let you send notification to administrator  that some accounts have new owners.

If you want to do it by workflow you would need additional field, new send email action and new field update.